# show menu bar in Chrome for sites that hide it

Tags: google-chrome

Some site open in a new window that does not have menu bar. Is there a way to overwrite this in Chrome? I want to have access to the full menu and the tab.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On some sites (such as for [AnandTech](http://www.anandtech.com/)'s "Print this article" feature), opening the link using a middle-click creates a new tab as normal.

Alternatively, but this is not automatic, you can right-click on the title bar of one of these new windows and select "Show as tab".

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Chrome-specific thing it's actually Javascript, which allows specifying the appearance when calling the new browser window.  Something to the effect of:

```
var popup = window.open('http://www.domain.com','','scrollbars=no,menubar=no,height=600,width=800,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no');
```

I don't use Chrome, but I've found that in IE, I can usually get away with activating the pop-up and then hitting <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> to open the popped-up window in a New browser window, which will have the location bar, be resizable, etc.  I'm pretty sure Chrome uses the same keyboard shortcut.

Comment: In Chrome, pressing Ctrl N just opens a blank new window.

Comment: Yeah I found a list, and it seems the only way to get a new window of the current tab (instead of just blank) is to drag the tab off the browser window.  Not sure if that's an option in the pop-up window the OP is seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I use a simple add-on called [Merge Windows](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/merge-windows/mmpokgfcmbkfdeibafoafkiijdbfblfg) in Chrome.

If a popup window decides to have menu bar hidden, I can use the tool to 'pull' that window into the main window with tabs and menu bars available.

Comment: This is a neat tool, but it doesn't work for sandboxed popup windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Tab Manager on Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-manager/eobcjlgohobbfcgabmijkdgpjkknpbbo) to move a tab/window without a menu/tab bar into another one. Once you've done that, you'll have your controls back and you can move the tab back out into its own window again while retaining controls.

After seeing @peter's suggestion, I remembered I had this extension and thought it might work, which it does for Facebook Messenger calls.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).